# I need gender ratio of user friends from Facebook Graph Api

Tags: php, laravel-5, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I know Facebook does not give list of friends list who have not accepted permission our app ask, I don't need actual names of friends. I just need gender ratios of my friend list. Is there any way for that?

I've tried some solution like:-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/

But these services were deprecated on April 4th, 2018.

So, any another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

1. Get the actual names of friends( You are going to need them)
2. Find a way to retrieve gender of the [retrieved names] using https://genderize.io/ API or https://gender-api.com/. Note though that it's algorithms are not perfectly true.
3. Then once you have genders of the list of your users you can then compute the gender ratio.

Comment: But the issue is facebook graph api is not providing the list of all friend. It returns I only those friends name who has given permission to our application for access their account information i.e, who has visited our application and connected with facebook on our application.

Comment: But the was not your question. Your question was you needed gender ration. And you acknowledged Facebook can not give you users' data when they have not authorized you to access it

Comment: Yes, My question was gender ratio. But your solution not work because Facebook is not providing list of all friends. and i already mention in my question:- **I know Facebook does not give list of friends list who have not accepted permission our app ask**

Comment: So you need gender ration of the list  of friends of a given user? or you need a gender ration of all the users retrieved?

Comment: Yes, i need gender ratio of user's friends.

Comment: With the new Facebook policy there is a possible work around here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: No, Inviteable_friends and tagable_friends Api's are deprecated after new polices. I've already read their docs and mentioned in my question as well.  Please check comments below the solution on link which you shared. Someone wrote, Now they are return nothing.

Comment: Well pal have you checked out this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1502515636638396/)